# Is it possible to change a variable’s value while it is in the `while` loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I was trying to write code to solve a question:

> Generate a random number between 1 and 9 (including 1 and 9). Ask the user to guess the number, then tell them whether they guessed too low, too high, or exactly right. Keep track of how many guesses the user has taken, and when the game ends, print this out.

The code that I wrote was:

```
import sys
import random
x=random.randint(1,9)

print('Hello there! Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.')

for i in range (10):
    z=input()
    if int(z)<x:
        print('Too low. Please try again.')

    elif int(z)>x:
        print('Too high. Please try again.')

    elif int(z)==x:
        print('You guessed it right!')

    if i==0:
        print('It took you a single turn! Nice')
    else:
        print('it took you ' + str(i+1)+' turns.')

    print('Do you want to play again? Yes or No?')

    j=input()
    if j.lower()=='yes':
        print('Okay, Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.') 
        pass
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

Here’s what it looks like when run:

```
Hello there! Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.
4
Too high. Please try again.
3
Too high. Please try again.
2
You guessed it right!
it took you 3 turns.
Do you want to play again? Yes or No?
yes
Okay, Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.
6
Too high. Please try again.
4
Too high. Please try again.
2
You guessed it right!
it took you 6 turns.
Do you want to play again? Yes or No?
```

See, the code gives perfect results when the `for` loop is first executed. It gives weird results when we try to run this “game” for the second time by saying `yes` when it asks us the question: `Do you want to play again? Yes or No?`.

Is it possible to put `i=0` when python reaches the 4th last line and the `for` loop starts again from `i=0` so that I do not get weird results?

Or is there some other easier method remove this bug?

Comment: use a while loop instead of for i in range(10). then reset the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use while loop for the task. And you should add exception handling method for getting an input.

```
import random

cond = True

while cond:
    print('Hello there! Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.')
    x=random.randint(1,9)
    for i in range (10):
        z=int(input())
        if int(z)<x:
            print('Too low. Please try again.')

        elif int(z)>x:
            print('Too high. Please try again.')

        elif int(z)==x:
            print('You guessed it right!')
            import sys
            if i==0:
                print('It took you a single turn! Nice')
            else:
                print('it took you ' + str(i+1)+' turns.')

            print('Do you want to play again? Yes or No?')
            j=input()
            if j.lower()=='yes':
                break
            else:
                cond = False
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please tell me that why did you put `cond=False` in the second last line? The code runs well without it too!

Comment: Because of ```sys.exit()``` statement program will exit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you pick the random number only once, so it's always going to be the same.

Secondly, your game should be in while loop instead of for loop (if you want to allow player to restart after they guessed).

```
turns = 0
while True:
    secret_number = random.randint(1,9)
    print('Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.')
    guess = input()
    turns += 1
    if int(guess) < secret_number:
        print("Too low")
    elif int(guess) > secret_number:
        print("Too high")
    else:
        print("You guessed in {} turn(s)".format(turns))
```

You continue the loop, and assign turns = 0 if user wants to keep playing, or you break if he doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it like this, probably.

```
from itertools import count
from random import randint


def run_game():
    random_value = randint(1, 9)
    print('Hello there! Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.')

    for i in count():
        guess_string = input()

        try:
            guess = int(guess_string)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid value given for guess: {}".format(guess_string))

        if guess < random_value:
            print("Too low! Please try again.")

        elif guess > random_value:
            print("Too high! Please try again.")

        else:   
            print('You guessed it right!')

            if not i:
                print('It took you a single turn! Nice')
            else:
                print('it took you {} turns.'.format(i + 1))

            print('Do you want to play again? Yes or No?')

            response_string = input()
            return response_string.lower() == 'yes'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while run_game():
        pass
```

But, for simplicity in understanding:

```
from itertools import count
from random import randint

if __name__ == "__main__":
    playing = True
    while playing:
        random_value = randint(1, 9)
        print('Hello there! Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.')

        for i in count():
            guess_string = input()

            try:
                guess = int(guess_string)
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid value given for guess: {}".format(guess_string))

            if guess < random_value:
                print("Too low! Please try again.")

            elif guess > random_value:
                print("Too high! Please try again.")

            else:
                print('You guessed it right!')

                if not i:
                    print('It took you a single turn! Nice')
                else:
                    print('it took you {} turns.'.format(i + 1))

                print('Do you want to play again? Yes or No?')

                response_string = input()
                if response_string.lower() != 'yes':
                    playing = False
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

All imports should go at the top of the file. Then, put a while loop so the player can restart after every game; this way, the variable x is also reset after every game. Also, the first print should be put outside the while and for loop, so it's printed only one time (the last if will print a new prompt at the beginning of a new game).
Your code at this point should look like this:

```
import random
import sys
print('Hello there! Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.')
while True:
   x=random.randint(1,9)
   for i in range (10):
       z=input()
       if int(z)<x:
           print('Too low. Please try again.')
       elif int(z)>x:
           print('Too high. Please try again.')
       elif int(z)==x:
           print('You guessed it right!')
           if i==0:
               print('It took you a single turn! Nice')
           else:
               print('it took you ' + str(i+1)+' turns.')
           print('Do you want to play again? Yes or No?')
           j=input()
           if j.lower()=='yes':
               print('Okay, Please enter a number between 1 and 9 including the extremes.') 
           else:
               sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole of your code is embedded within the for loop and the counter is never reset. If you want to reset i within the for loop, you have to define it outside the for loop so that it has a global scope.

Comment: That would not work. even if I declared i as a global variable, it would be changed as soon as i enters the for loop.